# Use Android Open Specific folder in Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am programming an app that use a string (e.g. full name = "Adam Smith") and thus open corresponding "Adam Smith" folder in google drive. The next step is to show the content inside the folder.

Actually I am now able to access into google drive but unable to go into this specific folder. Can anyone post a sample code for me since I read the GoogleAPI webpage but cannot finish my app.

I am appreciated for suggestion in advance. Thank you

Comment: When you create a folder or file in that you will get a driveid .Using that only you can access the file or folder.           complete sample code are here   https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#list_a_folders_contents) that Folders provide a convenience method for listing their direct children using [`DriveFolder.listChildren`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFolder.html#listChildren(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)). The [sample code](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesInFolderActivity.java) illustrates how to list files in a folder.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onCreate(connectionHint);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
    mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
    mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
    mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
    DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), sFolderId);
    folder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(childrenRetrievedCallback);
}

ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> childrenRetrievedCallback = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
            return;
        }
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
        mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
        showMessage("Successfully listed files.");
    }
```

You can see more examples [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/).

Here are some related SO posts which might also help:

- [Android Google Drive SDK - how to show list of files in selected folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859425/android-google-drive-sdk-how-to-show-list-of-files-in-selected-folder)
- [Listing files and folders of GDrive using Google Drive Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153496/listing-files-and-folders-of-gdrive-using-google-drive-api)

Happy coding!